# Abort link & form submit while sending the requests using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, form-submit

I have links and forms in my website that send requests to server

After of those requests the pages should be reloaded, so Ajax - Xmlhttprequest should be avoided in my case

Some of these requests maybe need a long time to be executed

I want to give to the users the possibility to abort request of  or the submitted form by click a button (Abort it) like the x button of browsers

I know that is possible in Ajax case using the `abort()` function, but how can I make the same for the native links and forms ?

P.S. I tried to use `window.stop()` and `document.execCommand('Stop')` but no luck

Comment: seems weird... what is the use case to stop the submission? Problem with submission is basically the  page has "exited" so not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't the people already exited the page. You can only abort ajax requests [XMLHttpRequest#abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort).

Comment: Is there any documentation about it ? I know about the abort ajax function. Imagine users waiting to reload the page with results. Browsers have this funcionallity

Comment: According to the [DOM interface of form element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), there is no attribute or method to abort form submission on form element level.

Comment: The best solution is show a loading before you posting when the page update with some content the loading will disappear, you can put a link to a "cancel" and try to force the client redirect to another link, but you cant abort a form post.